# How to store two variables at the same time in an array or in different data structure

Tags: arrays, class, kotlin, timestamp

I want to store two variables ,one is Timestamp and second is Alpha Value at the same time .

Using below code I am not getting expected result.

```
    timeStampArray.add(rawData.received_at)
    alphaValuesArray.add(Math.toDegrees(result))
```

Could anybody help for how to store two variables using different methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time"?

Comment: What is the expected result? What are you getting?

Comment: If I got it right, you want to store an object with 2 properties (current timestamp and alpha value) in an array, and for this, you will need to create a class for this project and use a mutable list